# Limit of $f(x)/x$ given $f$ has periodic derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has periodic derivative: that is, $f'(x+c)=f'(x)$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists.

My attempt: The period does not matter. Showing it for one $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ shows it for any such with the same proof so you might as well assume period $1$ or $2\pi$. Trying a few examples, if $f(x)=\sin x$ then the limit is 0. If $f(x)=ax+\sin x$ then the limit is $a$. So it seems as if the limit should be the limit of $f'(x)/x$ as $x \to \infty$. I assume period $1$ for convenience.

We have $f(x)$ differentiable on $[1,x+1]$, so that by the Mean Value Theorem, $f(x+1)-f(1)=f'(c)x$ for some $c \in [1,x+1]$. Dividing by $x$ brings us close to what we want. But all the algebraic manipulations I've tried using the Mean Value Theorem on the intervals $[1,x], [1,x+1],[x,x+1]$ have come up terribly short. Are these the right intervals to try or am I off with what the limit should be?

Comment: I'd be interested to see if anyone can use more elementary machinery (e.g. the mean value theorem), but the approach that occurs to me would be to use fundamental theorem of calculus to integrate (functional) equation $f'(x+c)=f(x)$ on both sides with respect to $x$ to obtain a useful form that quickly gives proof.

Comment: Is $f'$ continuous? You'd need that in order to use fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @FrancisBegbie $f'$ is not necessarily continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because $f(x) = C+\int_0^x f'(t) dt$ and $f'(t+a) = f'(t)$ :

$$\int_0^{n a} f'(t) dt = n \int_0^a f'(t) dt$$

so that 
$$f(x) = C+\lfloor x / a \rfloor \int_0^a f'(t) dt + \int_0^{x-a \lfloor x / a \rfloor} f'(t) dt = x \int_0^a \frac{f'(t)}{a} dt + \mathcal{O}(1)$$

Answer (score 1):

The key is to realizing that the map
$$ x\mapsto f(x+c)-f(x) $$
is constant, since the map has derivative $f'(x+c)-f'(x) = 0$. Let $C$ satisfy $f(x+c)-f(x) = C$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I claim that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} = \frac{C}{c}$.

To see this, let $M = \max\limits_{x\in[0,c]}{|f(x)|}$ (note that $M$ exists because $f$ is continuous). For each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\bar{x}$ be the greatest integer multiple of $c$ less than $x$. We then have
\begin{align*} f(x) &= (f(x)-f(x-c)) + (f(x-c)-f(x-2c)) + \dots + (f(x-\bar{x}+c)-f(x-\bar{x})) + f(x-\bar{x}) \\
&= \frac{\bar{x}}{c}C + f(x-\bar{x}) 
\end{align*}
and hence
$$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{\frac{\bar{x}}{c}C + f(x-\bar{x})}{\bar{x}}\frac{\bar{x}}{x}} = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\frac{C}{c} + \frac{f(x-\bar{x})}{\bar{x}}\right)\frac{\bar{x}}{x}}$$
Since $x-\bar{x}\in[0,c]$ for all $x$, we have $|f(x-\bar{x})|\le M$ for all $x$, and hence $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x-\bar{x})}{\bar{x}}} = 0$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{\bar{x}}{x}} = 1$, the conclusion follows.